# Uncertainty about language in solving linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra

I am unsure about what is the correct (english) word to use in solving linear systems.  To be more specific, here is a good example.
Suppose to solve the following linear system of equations:

$\begin{cases}
x+y+z=0\\
-x+2z=0
\end{cases}$

Since these are two non parallel planes, they intersect in a straight line, so the system has $\infty^1$ solutions.  My question is about that $\infty$: is it **infinity** to the power of one or is it **infinite** to the power of one?

If this is not the appropriate setting for this type of question, I apologize.

Comment: @SalmonKiller My uncertainty comes from the way it is said in Italian language because $\infty^1$ is used as an adjective that qualifies the number of solutions, so it should be infinite to the power of one,  but to me it does not sound right because I look at it as the cardinality of the set of solutions.  Infinity sounds more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you say **infinity** to the power of one since that's the noun. I would say however that's an infinite line, plane, or if it's multi-dimensional I think it's better today it's a 4-dimensional infinite plane or something of this sort.